# Instantiate generic type

Tags: java

I'm trying to instantiate a new object by Class clazz like this:

**Code:**

```
public class EntityType {
    private Map json = null;
    public EntityType(Map json){
        this.json = json;
    }
    public <T> T getAs(Class<T> clazz){
        final Class<T> clz = clazz;
        T obj = null;
        try {
            if (checkMap(json)){
                obj = clz.newInstance();
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            if (e instanceof InstantiationException){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } else if (e instanceof IllegalAccessException){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } else {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }
}
```

This is how I use the code:

```
EntityType type = new EntityType(map); // map contains values 
User user = type.getAs(User.class);
```

`java.lang.InstantiationException` is thrown for the above code.

What could be wrong in my code?

**Update:**

```
    @Entity(name = "user")
    public class User { 
        @Id 
        private String id;
        @Column
        private String name;
        @Column
        private Long age;
        public User() {}
       // Setters and getter 
   }
```

Full stack trace:

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: org.goo.AnnotationTest$User
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
    at org.goodb.client.Goo$EntityType.getAs(Goo.java:90)
    at org.goo.AnnotationTest.doTest(AnnotationTest.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: What does the constructor for User look like?

Comment: it could possibly be that `User` class is an interface/abstract class

Comment: Can you show the `User` class?

Comment: @sp00m yah, see my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't have default constructor in your user's class

Comment: User class have a default constructor

Answer (score 1):

The exception stack trace says

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: org.goo.AnnotationTest$User
```

which suggests that `User` is a nested or inner class rather than a top-level one.  Static nested classes behave like top-level ones but for non-static inner classes, every instance is associated with a particular instance of its containing class and the compiler adds an extra parameter to the front of the parameter list for every constructor to pass in the appropriate containing instance.  What in the source code looks like

```
public User() {}
```

actually corresponds in the bytecode to something like

```
public User(AnnotationTest containingInstance) { this.container = containingInstance; }
```

(not with those parameter/field names but you get the idea).  So your `User` class does not in fact have a no-argument constructor.

If you declared the `User` class as a top-level class or marked it `static` then it would work as you expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

You have a generic method but you ain't passing it the type parameter. Try this:

```
 User user = type.<User>getAs(User.class);
```

If you share more code with us I can help you more. For example I'd like to see the full stack trace and the `User` class.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to implement this kind of code (from Google Http Client library) which does the same thing: User user = request.execute().parseAs(User.class);

Comment: I mean, the http client parseAs returns a class type of passed into the method

Answer (score 0):

As per javadoc description :

```
 * @exception  InstantiationException
 *               if this {@code Class} represents an abstract class,
 *               an interface, an array class, a primitive type, or void;
 *               or if the class has no nullary constructor;
 *               or if the instantiation fails for some other reason.
```

I think you do not have "nullary constructor", or most likely said : default constructor.